# cant remove element from java.util.list

Tags: java, c#, stanford-nlp

I'm using java.util in my c# program. I want to remove a element from List, however don't know why is is not working.

```
foreach (List sentence in new DocumentPreprocessor(clfile))
{
    //int i = sentence.size();
    string rm = "ASPECT";
    Object objstr = rm;

    sentence.remove(objstr);
    string temp2 = String.Join(",", sentence.toArray());
    ...
}
```

After execution of above coe the word "ASPECT" is still there in List sentence.

PS: Document Preprocessor belongs to, edu.stanford.nlp.process

Comment: You're using Java classes in C#?

Comment: Wait. What? `java.util` in C#?

Comment: Can't understand what is going on? `List sentence`, new keyword instead of collection.

Comment: yes, I integrated stanford.nlp.sharp in my current project using IKVM nugget.

Comment: @user3667737: Just curious why you need that kind of features?

Comment: there was a CRF algorithm used before that has annotated [ASPECT] tag to some words in my text. Now while syntactic dependency I want that annotated words but I dont want this [ASPECT] string in my text.

Comment: you can see c# sample here http://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/stanford-parser-is-available-on-nuget/

Comment: Hmm, if your tag is "[ASPECT]" and you try to remove "ASPECT", I would not expect to get removed. It is also possible that the list you get does not (only) contain Strings.

Comment: the list I get is like -LSB-, ASPECT, -RSB-, where lsb , rsb are right/left square brackets

Comment: this may help , but this my documentpreprocessor http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Natural-Language-Processing/Stanford-CoreNLP/edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor.java.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Javadoc of the Java version, there are no `String`s in that list:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor.html
, only `HasWord`s. Probably you should go through and remove by its toString() or find out the concrete implementation.

Comment: yes, does it mean list item are of type HasWord and need to convert my string to remove to HasWord type ...

Comment: No, it is enough to find out the index of those HasWords, you can use the remove method with int parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int) (and hope that method is supported in the underlying List implementation).

Comment: thanks that did the trick, I did like as follow               `string rm="ASPECT";            
 Object objstr = rm;

                Object [] s = sentence.toArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    string com = s[i].ToString();
                    if (com == "ASPECT")
                    {
                        sentence.remove(i);
                    }
                }`                                               but I think this will take time for my average document that will have 90k words each....anyway thanks a lot